# How to produce such results using SQL?

Tags: sql

use sql server 2019

source data：

customer

| ID | MemberID | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 101 | 2022-07-18 08:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 12 | 102 | 2022-08-18 08:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 12 | 103 | 2022-09-10 08:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 13 | 101 | 2022-10-11 08:00:00.000 |
| 5 | 13 | 102 | 2022-11-18 08:00:00.000 |
| 6 | 14 | 105 | 2022-12-12 08:00:00.000 |

Currently trying to use the following SQL syntax, does not meet my expectations

```
DECLARE @ids IdCollection;

insert into @ids
values (12)
insert into @ids
values (13)
insert into @ids
values (14)

select *
from customer a
inner join @ids i on a.MemberID = i.Value;
```

hope result：

| MemberID | 101 | 102 | 103 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-07-18 08:00:00.000 | 2022-08-18 08:00:00.000 | 2022-09-10 08:00:00.000 |
| 13 | 2022-10-11 08:00:00.000 | 2022-11-18 08:00:00.000 | null |
| 14 | null | null | null |

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of pivot query here:

```sql
SELECT
    a.MemberID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.Type = 101 THEN a.Date END) AS [101],
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.Type = 102 THEN a.Date END) AS [102],
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.Type = 103 THEN a.Date END) AS [103]
FROM customer a
INNER JOIN @ids i on a.MemberID = i.Value
GROUP BY a.MemberID
ORDER BY a.MemberID;
```

Comment: Thanks! ! Very nice, is there a cte recursive way?

Comment: I don't see how the concept of recursive CTE is applicable here.